# lscpu command shows more CPUs than the model indicates

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, intel, cpu, 21.10

According to [its listing page](https://www.newegg.com/silver-dell-latitude-e6540-workstation/p/N82E16834944302?Description=dell%20latitude%20e6540&cm_re=dell_latitude%20e6540-_-34-944-302-_-Product&quicklink=true), my laptop was supposed to have an Intel Core i7-4800MQ, but `lscpu` indicates it has an i7-4610M CPU instead. Obviously, I was given the wrong product, but I am confused because it also indicates that my 4610M has four CPUs instead of the two indicated by [Intel's CPU info page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/80345/intel-core-i74610m-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz/specifications.html). The 4800MQ has four CPUs.

I am running Xubuntu 21.10.

Is there an obvious reason why this discrepancy would be here, or is this likely just because I should've chosen my vendor more carefully?

```
user@Cola-Cola:~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           60
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4610M CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:                        3
CPU MHz:                         2394.652
CPU max MHz:                     3700.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        5986.10
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        4 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cach
                                 e flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rd
                                 tscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_
                                 good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmper
                                 f pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx e
                                 st tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_
                                 1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer
                                  aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fa
                                 ult epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp
                                  tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad f
                                 sgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms inv
                                 pcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear 
                                 flush_l1d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see 1 socket, 2 cores per socket, and 2 threads per core (as I'd expect for an Intel Core family processor with dual cores).  The CPU list (0-3) is reporting each thread as a CPU, because as far as the operating system or other software is concerned, that's the case: each thread is a "CPU".

This has always been the way hyperthreaded cores are reported.

Comment: I see, thank you for telling me.

Comment: The CPU you thought you were getting was probably the same core/thread count.  Generally, an i7 is an upgrade from an i5; if your clock speed is the same or better, you've gotten more than you paid for.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It's an i7 too.

Comment: That's what Google told me -- but they have the same max turbo, and the one you got has a higher "base speed" whatever that means.  IOW, the one you got is most likely superior to what was listed.

Comment: @ZeissIkon the 4610M is only a dual-core with HT, the 4800MQ is a quad-core with HT.